# Adapting a Complex System Command to subprocess.run()

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, command, system-calls

I am writing a Python3 script, which must run this system command on my Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS machine:

```
sudo su - otherUser -c "scp -P 1234 otherUser@10.10.10.10:/path/to/file/x.txt /tmp/x.txt"
```

When I manually paste this command into the server's command line, the command works just fine.  Now I need my Python script to execute it.  [Thanks to posts like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-do-i-execute-a-program-or-call-a-system-command), I believe that the `subprocess.run()` command should work here.

Here's my test code:

```
import subprocess

def main():
    subprocess.run(["ls", "-l"])            # For testing purposes
    print("===================================================================================")
    cmd = ["sudo", "su - otherUser", "-c", "\"scp -P 1234 otherUser@10.10.10.10:/path/to/file/x.txt /tmp/x.txt\""]
    print(cmd)        # see the command first
    subprocess.run(cmd)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output is:

```
me@ubuntu01$ python3 testSubprocess.py
total 4
-rw-r----- 1 demo demo 576 Jan 18 21:08 testSubprocess.py
===================================================================================
['sudo', 'su - otherUser', '-c', '"scp -P 1234 otherUser@10.10.10.10:/path/to/file/x.txt /tmp/x.txt"']
sudo: su - otherUser: command not found
me@ubuntu01$
```

As you can tell, I'm really confused about how to parse the command so that `subprocess.run()` can understand it.  The documentation ([here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments)) isn't that helpful for a beginner like me.  The format of `subprocess.run()` is:

```
subprocess.run(args, *, ...lots of other stuff...)
```

...where `args` is:

> args is required for all calls and should be a string, or a sequence
> of program arguments. Providing a sequence of arguments is generally
> preferred, as it allows the module to take care of any required
> escaping and quoting of arguments (e.g. to permit spaces in file
> names). If passing a single string, either shell must be True (see
> below) or else the string must simply name the program to be executed
> without specifying any arguments.

I don't fully follow that, but I do understand that `subprocess.run()` will take a list of strings that should be the command-to-be-executed.  Okay.  Can someone explain how to slice up my original command?

Answer (score 0):

Solution found by trial-and-error.  The original code defined the command like this:

```
cmd = ["sudo", "su - otherUser", "-c", "\"scp -P 1234 otherUser@10.10.10.10:/path/to/file/x.txt /tmp/x.txt\""]
```

...and the solution that worked:

```
cmd = ["sudo", "su", "otherUser", "-c", "scp -P 1234 otherUser@10.10.10.10:/path/to/file/x.txt /tmp/x.txt"]
```

i.e.:

- Broke up `"su - otherUser"` into `"su", "otherUser"`
- Removed the double quotes around the SCP command